# Run media files on Amazon S3 bucked via CloudFront through jwplayer using ETag

Tags: html, amazon-s3, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to run a audio file which is upload on amazon s3 bucket using cloudfront of Amazon. I am using jsplayer to run the video.

```
var baseURL = "https://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/";
jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    'id': 'playerID',
    'width': '480',
    'height': '270',
    'file': 'audio/song.mp3', /* change to your song/video path */
    'provider': 'rtmp',
    'streamer': 'rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/',
    'modes': [
            {
                type: 'html5',
                config: {
                    /* prepend your BUCKET URL (baseURL var) to the file path */
                    'file': baseURL + 'song.mp3',
                    /* set provider */
                    'provider': 'video'
            }
        }
     ]
});
```

This is working fine. But I don't want to pass the full url because of company policy. I have the ETag of the audio file. How can I use it to run the audio file.

Comment: *"I don't want to pass the full url because of company policy."* That doesn't seem to make a great deal of sense, at least on first reading.  If you are allowing someone to access a resource, why do the particular characters that make up the URL make a difference?

Comment: Nginx S3 proxy can help to do URL masking and check authenticity beforehand

Comment: Are you using JW6 or JW5?

Comment: jwplayer.version="5.9.2118"

Comment: If you are using RTMP. the provider has to be rtmp. For html5, set the provider to sound.